# R: fraction of elements in ddply?

Tags: r, plyr

I have a 3 column data frame. Need to summarize it and find a fraction of each element record w.r.t. total number of records in it's subgroup (not total overall). Summary works fine with `ddply`, but now I'm stuck with the fractions.

```
DataFrameCons = structure(list(Category = c("2-Way Radios/Intercoms", "2-Way Radios/Intercoms", 
                                            "2-Way Radios/Intercoms", "2-Way Radios/Intercoms", "2-Way Radios/Intercoms", 
                                            "2-Way Radios/Intercoms", "2-Way Radios/Intercoms", "2-Way Radios/Intercoms", 
                                            "2-Way Radios/Intercoms", "2-Way Radios/Intercoms", "2-Way Radios/Intercoms", 
                                            "2-Way Radios/Intercoms", "2-Way Radios/Intercoms", "2-Way Radios/Intercoms", 
                                            "2-Way Radios/Intercoms", "2-Way Radios/Intercoms", "2-Way Radios/Intercoms", 
                                            "2-Way Radios/Intercoms", "2-Way Radios/Intercoms", "2-Way Radios/Intercoms", 
                                            "2-Way Radios/Intercoms", "2-Way Radios/Intercoms", "2-Way Radios/Intercoms", 
                                            "2-Way Radios/Intercoms", "2-Way Radios/Intercoms", "2-Way Radios/Intercoms", 
                                            "2-Way Radios/Intercoms", "2-Way Radios/Intercoms", "2-Way Radios/Intercoms", 
                                            "2-Way Radios/Intercoms", "2-Way Radios/Intercoms", "2-Way Radios/Intercoms", 
                                            "2-Way Radios/Intercoms", "2-Way Radios/Intercoms", "2-Way Radios/Intercoms", 
                                            "2-Way Radios/Intercoms", "2-Way Radios/Intercoms", "2-Way Radios/Intercoms", 
                                            "2-Way Radios/Intercoms", "2-Way Radios/Intercoms", "2-Way Radios/Intercoms", 
                                            "2-Way Radios/Intercoms", "2-Way Radios/Intercoms", "2-Way Radios/Intercoms", 
                                            "2-Way Radios/Intercoms", "2-Way Radios/Intercoms", "2-Way Radios/Intercoms", 
                                            "2-Way Radios/Intercoms", "2-Way Radios/Intercoms", "2-Way Radios/Intercoms", 
                                            "2-Way Radios/Intercoms", "2-Way Radios/Intercoms", "2-Way Radios/Intercoms", 
                                            "2-Way Radios/Intercoms", "2-Way Radios/Intercoms", "2-Way Radios/Intercoms", 
                                            "2-Way Radios/Intercoms", "2-Way Radios/Intercoms", "2-Way Radios/Intercoms", 
                                            "2-Way Radios/Intercoms", "2-Way Radios/Intercoms", "2-Way Radios/Intercoms", 
                                            "2-Way Radios/Intercoms", "2-Way Radios/Intercoms", "2-Way Radios/Intercoms", 
                                            "2-Way Radios/Intercoms", "2-Way Radios/Intercoms", "2-Way Radios/Intercoms", 
                                            "2-Way Radios/Intercoms", "2-Way Radios/Intercoms", "2-Way Radios/Intercoms", 
                                            "2-Way Radios/Intercoms", "2-Way Radios/Intercoms", "2-Way Radios/Intercoms", 
                                            "2-Way Radios/Intercoms", "2-Way Radios/Intercoms", "2-Way Radios/Intercoms", 
                                            "2-Way Radios/Intercoms", "2-Way Radios/Intercoms", "2-Way Radios/Intercoms", 
                                            "2-Way Radios/Intercoms", "2-Way Radios/Intercoms", "2-Way Radios/Intercoms", 
                                            "2-Way Radios/Intercoms", "2-Way Radios/Intercoms", "2-Way Radios/Intercoms", 
                                            "2-Way Radios/Intercoms", "2-Way Radios/Intercoms", "2-Way Radios/Intercoms", 
                                            "2-Way Radios/Intercoms", "2-Way Radios/Intercoms", "2-Way Radios/Intercoms", 
                                            "2-Way Radios/Intercoms", "2-Way Radios/Intercoms", "2-Way Radios/Intercoms", 
                                            "2-Way Radios/Intercoms", "2-Way Radios/Intercoms", "2-Way Radios/Intercoms", 
                                            "2-Way Radios/Intercoms", "2-Way Radios/Intercoms", "2-Way Radios/Intercoms", 
                                            "2-Way Radios/Intercoms", "2-Way Radios/Intercoms", "2-Way Radios/Intercoms", 
                                            "2-Way Radios/Intercoms", "2-Way Radios/Intercoms", "2-Way Radios/Intercoms", 
                                            "2-Way Radios/Intercoms", "2-Way Radios/Intercoms", "2-Way Radios/Intercoms", 
                                            "2-Way Radios/Intercoms", "2-Way Radios/Intercoms", "2-Way Radios/Intercoms", 
                                            "2-Way Radios/Intercoms", "2-Way Radios/Intercoms", "2-Way Radios/Intercoms", 
                                            "2-Way Radios/Intercoms", "2-Way Radios/Intercoms", "2-Way Radios/Intercoms", 
                                            "Acne Treatments", "Acne Treatments", "Acne Treatments", "Acne Treatments", 
                                            "Acne Treatments", "Acne Treatments", "Acne Treatments", "Acne Treatments", 
                                            "Acne Treatments", "Acne Treatments", "Acne Treatments", "Acne Treatments", 
                                            "Acne Treatments", "Acne Treatments", "Acne Treatments", "Acne Treatments", 
                                            "Acne Treatments", "Acne Treatments", "Acne Treatments", "Acne Treatments", 
                                            "Acne Treatments", "Acne Treatments", "Acne Treatments", "Acne Treatments", 
                                            "Acne Treatments", "Acne Treatments", "Acne Treatments", "Acne Treatments", 
                                            "Acne Treatments", "Acne Treatments", "Acne Treatments", "Acne Treatments", 
                                            "Acne Treatments", "Acne Treatments", "Acne Treatments", "Acne Treatments", 
                                            "Acne Treatments", "Acne Treatments", "Acne Treatments", "Acne Treatments", 
                                            "Acne Treatments", "Acne Treatments", "Acne Treatments", "Acne Treatments", 
                                            "Acne Treatments", "Acne Treatments", "Acne Treatments", "Acne Treatments", 
                                            "Acne Treatments", "Acne Treatments", "Acne Treatments", "Acne Treatments", 
                                            "Acne Treatments", "Acne Treatments", "Acne Treatments", "Acne Treatments", 
                                            "Acne Treatments", "Acne Treatments", "Acne Treatments", "Acne Treatments", 
                                            "Acne Treatments", "Acne Treatments", "Acne Treatments", "Acne Treatments", 
                                            "Acne Treatments", "Acne Treatments", "Acne Treatments", "Acne Treatments", 
                                            "Acne Treatments", "Acne Treatments", "Acne Treatments", "Acne Treatments", 
                                            "Acne Treatments", "Acne Treatments", "Acne Treatments", "Acne Treatments", 
                                            "Acne Treatments", "Acne Treatments", "Acne Treatments", "Acne Treatments", 
                                            "Acne Treatments", "Acne Treatments", "Acne Treatments", "Acne Treatments", 
                                            "Acne Treatments", "Acne Treatments", "Acne Treatments", "Acne Treatments", 
                                            "Acne Treatments", "Acne Treatments", "Acne Treatments", "Acne Treatments", 
                                            "Acne Treatments", "Acne Treatments", "Acne Treatments", "Acne Treatments"
), Manufacturer = c("Other", "Other", "Other", "Other", "Other", 
                    "Other", "Other", "Other", "Other", "Other", "Other", "Other", 
                    "Other", "Other", "Other", "Other", "Other", "Other", "Other", 
                    "Other", "Other", "Other", "Other", "Other", "Other", "Other", 
                    "Other", "Other", "Other", "Other", "Other", "Other", "Other", 
                    "Other", "Other", "Other", "Other", "Other", "Other", "Other", 
                    "Other", "Other", "Other", "Other", "Other", "Other", "Other", 
                    "Motorola Inc", "Motorola Inc", "Motorola Inc", "Motorola Inc", 
                    "Motorola Inc", "Motorola Inc", "Motorola Inc", "Motorola Inc", 
                    "Motorola Inc", "Motorola Inc", "Motorola Inc", "Motorola Inc", 
                    "Motorola Inc", "Motorola Inc", "Motorola Inc", "Motorola Inc", 
                    "Motorola Inc", "Motorola Inc", "Motorola Inc", "Motorola Inc", 
                    "Motorola Inc", "Motorola Inc", "Hasbro Inc", "Hasbro Inc", "Hasbro Inc", 
                    "Other", "Other", "Other", "Other", "Other", "Other", "Other", 
                    "Other", "Other", "Other", "Other", "Other", "Other", "Other", 
                    "Other", "Other", "Other", "Other", "Other", "Other", "Other", 
                    "Other", "Other", "Other", "Other", "Other", "Other", "Other", 
                    "Other", "Other", "Other", "Other", "Other", "Other", "Other", 
                    "Other", "Other", "Other", "Other", "Other", "Other", "Other", 
                    "Other", "Other", "Other", "Other", "Other", "3M", "3M", "Laboratory Robaina Inc", 
                    "University Medical Pharmaceuticals", "University Medical Pharmaceuticals", 
                    "University Medical Pharmaceuticals", "University Medical Pharmaceuticals", 
                    "University Medical Pharmaceuticals", "University Medical Pharmaceuticals", 
                    "University Medical Pharmaceuticals", "University Medical Pharmaceuticals", 
                    "University Medical Pharmaceuticals", "University Medical Pharmaceuticals", 
                    "University Medical Pharmaceuticals", "University Medical Pharmaceuticals", 
                    "University Medical Pharmaceuticals", "University Medical Pharmaceuticals", 
                    "University Medical Pharmaceuticals", "University Medical Pharmaceuticals", 
                    "University Medical Pharmaceuticals", "University Medical Pharmaceuticals", 
                    "University Medical Pharmaceuticals", "University Medical Pharmaceuticals", 
                    "University Medical Pharmaceuticals", "University Medical Pharmaceuticals", 
                    "University Medical Pharmaceuticals", "University Medical Pharmaceuticals", 
                    "University Medical Pharmaceuticals", "University Medical Pharmaceuticals", 
                    "University Medical Pharmaceuticals", "University Medical Pharmaceuticals", 
                    "University Medical Pharmaceuticals", "University Medical Pharmaceuticals", 
                    "University Medical Pharmaceuticals", "University Medical Pharmaceuticals", 
                    "University Medical Pharmaceuticals", "University Medical Pharmaceuticals", 
                    "University Medical Pharmaceuticals", "University Medical Pharmaceuticals", 
                    "University Medical Pharmaceuticals", "University Medical Pharmaceuticals", 
                    "University Medical Pharmaceuticals", "University Medical Pharmaceuticals", 
                    "University Medical Pharmaceuticals", "University Medical Pharmaceuticals", 
                    "University Medical Pharmaceuticals", "University Medical Pharmaceuticals", 
                    "University Medical Pharmaceuticals", "University Medical Pharmaceuticals", 
                    "University Medical Pharmaceuticals", "University Medical Pharmaceuticals", 
                    "University Medical Pharmaceuticals", "University Medical Pharmaceuticals", 
                    "University Medical Pharmaceuticals", "University Medical Pharmaceuticals", 
                    "University Medical Pharmaceuticals", "University Medical Pharmaceuticals", 
                    "University Medical Pharmaceuticals", "University Medical Pharmaceuticals", 
                    "University Medical Pharmaceuticals", "University Medical Pharmaceuticals", 
                    "University Medical Pharmaceuticals", "University Medical Pharmaceuticals", 
                    "University Medical Pharmaceuticals", "University Medical Pharmaceuticals", 
                    "University Medical Pharmaceuticals", "University Medical Pharmaceuticals", 
                    "University Medical Pharmaceuticals", "University Medical Pharmaceuticals", 
                    "University Medical Pharmaceuticals", "University Medical Pharmaceuticals", 
                    "University Medical Pharmaceuticals", "University Medical Pharmaceuticals", 
                    "University Medical Pharmaceuticals", "University Medical Pharmaceuticals", 
                    "University Medical Pharmaceuticals", "University Medical Pharmaceuticals", 
                    "University Medical Pharmaceuticals", "University Medical Pharmaceuticals", 
                    "University Medical Pharmaceuticals", "University Medical Pharmaceuticals", 
                    "University Medical Pharmaceuticals", "University Medical Pharmaceuticals", 
                    "University Medical Pharmaceuticals", "University Medical Pharmaceuticals", 
                    "University Medical Pharmaceuticals", "University Medical Pharmaceuticals", 
                    "University Medical Pharmaceuticals", "University Medical Pharmaceuticals", 
                    "University Medical Pharmaceuticals", "University Medical Pharmaceuticals", 
                    "University Medical Pharmaceuticals", "University Medical Pharmaceuticals", 
                    "University Medical Pharmaceuticals", "Other", "Other"), Count = c(1, 
                                                                                       1, 2, 1, 1, 1, 1, 6, 1, 1, 1, 2, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 3, 1, 1, 
                                                                                       1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 
                                                                                       3, 1, 1, 1, 49, 206, 62, 4, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 1, 1, 244, 1, 16, 
                                                                                       1, 1, 1, 2, 1, 2, 1, 16, 57, 1, 1, 1, 1, 6, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 
                                                                                       1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 60, 109, 
                                                                                       2, 7, 9, 6, 88, 1, 2, 1, 2, 3, 1, 3, 2, 5, 3, 2, 1, 1, 2, 4, 
                                                                                       1, 4, 1, 1, 3, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 19, 1, 1, 2, 3, 1, 4, 1, 1, 1, 
                                                                                       79, 1, 143, 1, 3, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 77, 1, 1, 1, 33, 1, 3, 
                                                                                       1, 1, 63, 3, 3, 1, 5, 1, 10, 1, 663, 976, 1, 2, 1, 43, 1, 1, 
                                                                                       4, 241, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 86, 1, 1, 3, 1, 244, 84, 1, 1, 1, 659, 
                                                                                       1, 265, 13, 5, 1, 1, 169, 9, 38, 1, 1, 2014, 5, 3, 2, 1, 1, 2, 
                                                                                       1)), .Names = c("Category", "Manufacturer", "Count"), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
                                                                                                                                                                                 215L))

counts_data_cons = ddply(DataFrameCons,.(Category,Manufacturer),summarise,records = sum(Count))#, manu = paste(unique(Manufacturer),collapse = "; "))    
View(counts_data_cons)
```

Output:

```
                Category                       Manufacturer records
1 2-Way Radios/Intercoms                         Hasbro Inc      59
2 2-Way Radios/Intercoms                       Motorola Inc     615
3 2-Way Radios/Intercoms                              Other     399
4        Acne Treatments                                 3M       6
5        Acne Treatments             Laboratory Robaina Inc       1
6        Acne Treatments                              Other       3
7        Acne Treatments University Medical Pharmaceuticals    6039
```

Desired output:

```
                Category                       Manufacturer records frac
1 2-Way Radios/Intercoms                         Hasbro Inc      59 0.055
2 2-Way Radios/Intercoms                       Motorola Inc     615 0.573
3 2-Way Radios/Intercoms                              Other     399 0.372
4        Acne Treatments                                 3M       6 9.9e-4
5        Acne Treatments             Laboratory Robaina Inc       1 1.7e-4
6        Acne Treatments                              Other       3 5.0e-4
7        Acne Treatments University Medical Pharmaceuticals    6039 0.998
```

where 0.055 = 59 / (59 + 615 + 399). Thanks!
If possible, not using `dplyr` package

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do it like this using `plyr`:

```
library(plyr)
ddply(counts_data_cons, .(Category), mutate, frac = records / sum(records))
#                Category                       Manufacturer records         frac
#1 2-Way Radios/Intercoms                         Hasbro Inc      59 0.0549860205
#2 2-Way Radios/Intercoms                       Motorola Inc     615 0.5731593663
#3 2-Way Radios/Intercoms                              Other     399 0.3718546132
#4        Acne Treatments                                 3M       6 0.0009918995
#5        Acne Treatments             Laboratory Robaina Inc       1 0.0001653166
#6        Acne Treatments                              Other       3 0.0004959497
#7        Acne Treatments University Medical Pharmaceuticals    6039 0.9983468342
```

Of course you could `round` the `frac` values as you wish inside the `ddply` call.

Comment: Thanks! So, a two-step process? I was thinking about that as well and that it's probably not very efficient (or may be even impossible) to make a one-step process. Anyways, it works and suits my needs!

Comment: @AlexeyFerapontov, the two steps require different grouping, first by category and Manufacturer, second only by category. That's why you'll need two steps. If you're worried about performance, you should look into `dplyr` or `data.table`